# python syntax error while trying to read a text file

Tags: python, syntax

I'm working on a python program that reads a text file, splits the file by semicolon, and then removes tabs and newlines. This is the code I have so far

```
myfile="F:\\Python\\Programs\\test.sas"
f=open(myfile,"r")
g=f.read()
statements=g.split(';')
statements.pop()
statements2=list()
for cue in statements:
    statements2.append(cue.strip("\n")
print(statements)
```

The text file it reads looks like this

```
data test1;
    set test;
run;

data test2;
    set test;
run;

data test3;
    set test2;
run;

data test4;
    set test3;
run;
```

I'm just starting to learn python so I'm not really sure where the problem is. The error I'm getting has an arrow pointing at the t in print, and says "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

I'm using python 3.4.3. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `statements2.append(cue.strip("\n")` you forgot to put closing bracket it should be `statements2.append(cue.strip("\n"))`.

Comment: By the way, you could use something like `g.replace('\n', '')` right after reading file

Comment: as a general rule if you have a syntax error the problem is either with the line shown or the line before. When I have one I simply assume missing parenthesis on the line before the one where the error appeared since I frequently do that myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are missing a trailing `)` in the previous line.

```
statements2.append(cue.strip("\n"))
```